# $\sum_{n\ge1}n^\alpha r^n<\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{(1-r)^{1+\alpha}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha,r\in(0,1)$. Show that
$$\sum_\limits{n\geq1}n^\alpha r^n<\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{(1-r)^{1+\alpha}}$$
and that the constant $\Gamma(1+\alpha)$ is best possible.

Edit: Just realized one can just expand the RHS and then it's already solved modulo some info on the generalized binomial coefficients.

Comment: 1. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.$$$$
2. Please show us your thoughts and attempts to solve this so that we can really help you and not just solve the problem for you.

Comment: What is going on with all the downvotes? I asked this question and soon after (before anyone answered) I edited it and said that I've solved it. Plus Gary answered the question anyways for any future readers. What should the downvotes effect now?

Comment: I don't even know how someone would see this question now? I mean it's answered and has almost no new views. Is it just some guy with multiple accounts?

Comment: @tetra Views grow with time. It seems you have an approach : why not elaborate on it more? The answer to the question isn't part of the context, because it doesn't talk about the origins of the problem. A source for this question should be enough. If you have an approach, perhaps write one line about it in the question, and then add a self-answer (or let me know how it's done and I can add a detailed answer when I have the time).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer wdym? I already wrote about the approach (which  basically is the solution) and someone already answered. Why is the origin important? 90% of questions don't state the origin.

Comment: @tetra Questions typically don't state the origin : but they may state context in other forms, or (most often) contain detailed enough efforts towards solving the question. Your attempt contains too little information, in my opinion (of course, it is precisely that, which is why you are free to disagree). Context is a requirement for questions on this website. Once again, it takes very little time, and you are free to edit your question. All I'm saying is that the downvotes have to do with this part of your question : even if one person felt it was good enough to answer.

Comment: ok I'm done with this site. makes no sense at all to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\alpha, r \in (0,1)$. Note that
$$
\frac{{\Gamma (1 + \alpha )}}{{(1 - r)^{\alpha  + 1} }} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\Gamma (n + 1 + \alpha )}}{{\Gamma (n + 1)}}r^n } .
$$
Hence, it is enough to show that
$$
n^\alpha   < \frac{{\Gamma (n + 1 + \alpha )}}{{\Gamma (n + 1)}} \Longleftrightarrow 
\frac{{\Gamma (n + 1)}}{{\Gamma (n + 1 + \alpha )}} < \frac{1}{{n^\alpha  }}
$$
for all $n\geq 1$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. But \begin{align*}
\frac{{\Gamma (n + 1)}}{{\Gamma (n + 1 + \alpha )}} &= \frac{1}{{\Gamma (\alpha )}}\int_0^1 {t^{\alpha  - 1} (1 - t)^n {\rm d}t}  \le \frac{1}{{\Gamma (\alpha )}}\int_0^1 {t^{\alpha  - 1} {\rm e}^{ - nt} {\rm d}t} \\ & = \frac{1}{{n^\alpha  }}\frac{1}{{\Gamma (\alpha )}}\int_0^n {s^{\alpha  - 1} {\rm e}^{ - s} {\rm d}s}  < \frac{1}{{n^\alpha  }}\frac{1}{{\Gamma (\alpha )}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {s^{\alpha  - 1} {\rm e}^{ - s} {\rm d}s}  = \frac{1}{{n^\alpha  }}.
\end{align*}
By Stirling's formula,
$$
\frac{{\Gamma (n + 1 + \alpha )}}{{\Gamma (n + 1)}} \sim n^\alpha  
$$
as $n\to +\infty$, which indicates that the constant $\Gamma(1+\alpha)$ cannot be improved.